# If I have code in Python3.4 and I install latest Python3, am I able to force IDLE to use specific version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I have code written in Python3 with dot version of 4 (3.4).

I want to install latest Python3 onto Windows 10. The latest version is 3.8.

- When it installs IDLE will also install.
- Is it possible to force Idle to "use" specific version? Similar to Java compile for specific
  version.

I do not want functions to be shown that are not available in 3.4.

As an aside, it does not matter what machine is used for IDE and development. Python 3.x behaves the same on Windows as it does on CentOs as it does on Mac?

Comment: Found question that answer OS environment."The Windows version of Python doesn’t include the curses module. A ported version called UniCurses is available."

Answer (score 0):

Short answer 'No'.

Reason 1a is that if you have, in this instance, 3.4, you also have or can get the 3.4 version of IDLE and can use that.  Admittedly the old version is not as nice as the current version.  But IDLE is currently the same in all 'current' versions, which is now 3.8 to 3.10.  And IDLE for 3.7 is not much different.

Or 1b, you can edit a file with current IDLE (leaving aside the issues you raised), save it, and run it with 3.4 from (on Windows) Command Prompt.

The above assume that 3.4 still exits and runs an on a particular machine.  So 1c, you can try running your 3.4 code with 3.8.  Because we mostly try to not break backward compatibility, it might work as it, or with little change.  This should be especially true of code written by beginners.

Reason 2 is that the IDLE that comes with Python 3.x must be written to run in Python 3.x.  (Actually, the IDLE code is kept almost the same across current versions, so IDLE is currently limited to what runs on 3.8.)  To run your code, Python 3.x is started in a subprocess.  The first code it runs is the 3.x version of idlelib.run, which provides the connection to IDLE in the IDLE process.  For IDLE Shell, it also simulates interactive mode.

Reason 3 is that any attempt to work around reason 2 would be expensive, as it would require paid work and separate test machines.